combine class properties to reduce the code lines
I want to combine class properties
this
<?php 
$pagination = new Pagination();
$pagination->setLink("$appDir/category/?c=$c&p=%s");
$pagination->setPage($p);
$pagination->setSize($size);
$pagination->setTotalRecords($total);
$navigation = $pagination->create_links();
 ?>

will be like
$pagination = new Pagination();
$pagination->setLink("$appDir/category/?c=$c&p=%s");
$navigation = $pagination->setPage($p)->setSize($size)->setTotalRecords($total)->create_links();

I want to reduce the code lines

@shingo , Ok similar , but I do not know, where is the issue , I guess that there is no mistack in the code , but it;s not work

The main thing to use in the duplicate is about methods returning return $this;. It means that the next called method also operates on the initial object.
